# How to access environment variables in grunt application *after* it has been built

Tags: gruntjs, docker

### Application

I have an angularjs application that is built by grunt which uses grunt to inject environment variables (like API endpoints) into the angularjs code. However this problem is more specific to grunt applications being deployed in docker containers.

### Motivation

I've just recently started trying to integrate docker into the deployment process ([something similar to this](http://www.centurylinklabs.com/build-a-2-container-app-with-docker/)) but realized I don't know how to best get the environment variables into the application anymore. I'll describe the sequence of events:

1. Make changes to my code
2. Build a complete docker image that accepts API endpoints as environment variables
3. Push the docker image to my server
4. Run a container based off this new image

As you can see, grunt build occurs in step 2, but the environment variables are not available until step 4.

### Possible Solution

I *could* wrap the call to start the static server for my angular application in a small bash script which creates a javascript file containing the environment variable. I could then add a `<script>` tag in my `index.html` to import it and then start the server as usual, with everything working. However that feels like I'm sidestepping grunt inappropriately.

Does anyone know of a straightforward way to inject environment variables into client side code around the same time the `connect:dist:keepalive` task runs? To clarify, I'm already using the `ng-constant` grunt task but that can only access environment variables at build time, not server startup time.

Comment: I ended up slipping the bash script which injects some code into the container. It works.